# How to get checkbox,EditText with ListView values in android while clicking a button?

Tags: android, listview, checkbox, android-edittext

I m a new bee to Android world. I have a listview which has checkbox and EditText in it.  When I display records in the listview, I will check the checkbox and enter text in the editText field. I will do in many rows in the same. I have a button called Save. Using this I want to save the details of listview with newly added text and checkbox value. I do not know how to get the values when i click the save button. Please guide me. Here is the code.

main.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<TextView android:id="@+id/TextView01" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="List of items" android:textStyle="normal|bold"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"></TextView>
<ListView android:id="@+id/ListView01" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent">
</ListView>
<Button android:text="Save" android:id="@+id/btnSave"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
</Button>
</LinearLayout>
```

listview.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:gravity="left|center"
android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:paddingBottom="5px"
android:paddingTop="5px" android:paddingLeft="5px">
<TextView android:id="@+id/TextView01" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:gravity="center"
    android:textColor="#FFFF00" android:text="hi"></TextView>
<TextView android:text="hello" android:id="@+id/TextView02"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10px" android:textColor="#0099CC"></TextView>
<EditText android:id="@+id/txtbox" android:layout_width="120px"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:textSize="12sp"
    android:layout_x="211px" android:layout_y="13px">
</EditText>
<CheckBox android:id="@+id/chkbox1" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

CustomListViewActivity.java:

```
package com.listivew;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class CustomListViewActivity extends ListActivity {
ListView l1;
static Context mContext;
Button btnSave;
private static class EfficientAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;

    public EfficientAdapter(Context context) {
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);

    }

    public int getCount() {
        return country.length;
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.listview, parent,
                    false);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.text = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.TextView01);
            holder.text2 = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.TextView02);
            holder.txt = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtbox);
            holder.cbox = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.chkbox1);

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        holder.text.setText(curr[position]);
        holder.text2.setText(country[position]);
        holder.txt.setText("");
        holder.cbox.setChecked(false);

        return convertView;
    }

    public class ViewHolder {
        TextView text;
        TextView text2;
        EditText txt;
        CheckBox cbox;
    }
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    l1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ListView01);
    l1.setAdapter(new EfficientAdapter(this));
    btnSave = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnSave);
    mContext = this;

    btnSave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // I want to print the text which is in the listview one by one. 
            //Later i will insert it in the database
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "EditText Value, checkbox value and other values", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });
}

private static final String[] country = { "item1", "item2", "item3",
        "item4", "item5", "item6" };
private static final String[] curr = { "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6" };

}
```

Comment: Not clear with your question. You want to push your content to details activity or what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
btnSave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
         for (int i = 0; i <l1.getCount() ; i++) {
             View vListSortOrder;
                    vListSortOrder=l1.getChildAt(i);     
                    try{
                    EditText edit=(EditText)vListSortOrder.findViewById(R.id.share_comment_edit);
                   String temp=edit.getText().toString();

        }
      }
    });
```

Similarly create a object for your CheckBox and get its state. Simple.

Comment: Hi Andro Selva, Thank you for your reply. I tried this. But I did not succeed. We cannot create Edit Text with id reference '(EditText edit=(EditText)vListSortOrder.findViewById(R.id.share_comment_edit);)'. Because I have the EditText in ListView.xml file. But I have the save button in main.xml file. I cannot access it outside. It shows this error when i tried your code. **ERROR/AndroidRuntime(282): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: 
Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'**

Comment: Replace your Activity to extend "Activity"instead of ListActivity.Instead of CustomListViewActivity extends ListActivity  try CustomListViewActivity extends Activity

Comment: Hi dude, Thanks for your reply. It works fine. I changed the ListActivity to Activity in the CustomeListViewActivity. Great help. Thanks a lot. :)

Comment: I am doing similar kind, but  EditText edit is returning null always

Answer (score 0):

I know that edittext uses the following:

```
holder.txt = ((EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtbox).getEditableText()).toString();
```