# Is there any way to enable Edittext with Checkbox in Listview?

Tags: android, listview, checkbox, android-edittext, android-checkbox

I'm trying to create a `listview` with each row having a `checkbox` and `edittext`. I've made `edittext` enabled on `checkbox` checked event by using `notifyDatasetChanged()`.

But it resets position which makes it difficult to track current position. I've created an instance variable to keep track of current position on `checkbox` checked event, but that too resets to the last item checked.

The `checkbox` works fine. It enables `edittext` when checked and disables on uncheck, also checked status is fine. But the problem is `edittext` only getting last checked value if I use `listposition`, and `last item` if I use `position`.

My adapter is given below:

```
public class ListViewAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Model> implements TextWatcher{

private final List<Model> list;
private final Context context;
private int listPosition;
private ViewHolder newHolder = null;

public ListViewAdapter(Context context, List<Model> list) {
    super(context, R.layout.row, list);
    this.context = context;
    this.list = list;
}

public static class ViewHolder {
    public CheckBox mCheckBox;
    public EditText mEditText;
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {

    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflator = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        convertView = inflator.inflate(R.layout.row, null);
        newHolder = new ViewHolder();
        newHolder.mCheckBox = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkbox);
        newHolder.mEditText = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtValue);
        newHolder.mCheckBox.setText(list.get(position).getCheckText());
        newHolder.mEditText.setText(list.get(position).getValue());
        setEdit(false);

        convertView.setTag(newHolder);
        convertView.setTag(R.id.checkbox, newHolder.mCheckBox);
        convertView.setTag(R.id.txtValue, newHolder.mEditText);
    } else {
        newHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    newHolder.mCheckBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {
            int getPosition = (int) compoundButton.getTag();
            list.get(getPosition).setSelected(compoundButton.isChecked());
            list.get(getPosition).setEnabled(compoundButton.isChecked());
            setEdit(compoundButton.isChecked());
            listPosition = getPosition;
            if(!compoundButton.isChecked()){
                list.get(getPosition).setValue("");
            }
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });

    newHolder.mCheckBox.setTag(position); 
    newHolder.mEditText.setTag(position);
    newHolder.mEditText.addTextChangedListener(this);
    setEdit(list.get(position).isEnabled());
    return convertView;
}

public void setEdit(boolean bool){
    newHolder.mEditText.setEnabled(bool);
    newHolder.mEditText.setFocusableInTouchMode(bool);
    newHolder.mEditText.setCursorVisible(bool);
}

@Override
public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {}

@Override
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {}

@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
    list.get(listPosition).setValue(s.toString());
}

}
```

Comment: I'm not sure why you are needing to set tags and get positions in the list. The `getView`  method has a position parameter for the current row. Also `notifyDatasetChanged` only needs to be called if you edit the `Model` at that position, so maybe you should do that instead and base how the view is drawn  on that

Comment: See this : http://stackoverflow.com/a/18671362/4813855 and http://stackoverflow.com/a/36542854/4813855 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10536128/how-to-get-checkbox-edittext-with-listview-values-in-android-while-clicking-a-bu and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21548722/custom-listview-with-edittext-checkbox-and-textview

Comment: See this for solving how to get position of your item http://www.mysamplecode.com/2012/07/android-listview-checkbox-example.html

Comment: @cricket_007 I need to call `notifyDatasetChanged` to  enable/disable `EditText`. The position parameter given in `getView` method resets to `last position` once we call `notifyDatasetChanged`. I tried using it earlier, but it didn't work. Also present code works fine if I check one item and enter text in the corresponding `EditText`, but fails if any user enters text in a non-current row.

Comment: Maybe that's because `afterTextChanged` only uses the row of the last checkbox that was selected and only updates that Model. You might want to call notifyDatasetChanged there as well

Comment: `notifyDatasetChanged` takes more resources, so it's not a good idea to use it often. Also using it twice slows down or hangs app. You are right that `afterTextChanged` uses last checked value, that's the reason I'm looking for an alternative. I've tried using an int within `ViewHolder` and tagging it to `EditText`, but that too is getting same value as `position`.

Comment: @ERVishalSenjaliya My `checkbox` works fine, but the problem is retrieving text from `EditText`. The link you've posted is a simple `listview` to retrieve checked status.

Answer (score 0):

You should take arraylist to store checked position instead of storing into single interger. Define temp arraylist in your adpater and Create Hashmap to store value entered on specific edittext

```
ArrayList<String> selectedPosition = new ArrayList<String>();
HashMap<Integer, String> editHash = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
```

Now update your getView() method as per below :

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {

    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflator = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        convertView = inflator.inflate(R.layout.row, null);
        newHolder = new ViewHolder();
        newHolder.mCheckBox = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkbox);
        newHolder.mEditText = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtValue);
        newHolder.mCheckBox.setText(list.get(position).getCheckText());
        newHolder.mEditText.setText(list.get(position).getValue());
        setEdit(false);

        convertView.setTag(newHolder);
        convertView.setTag(R.id.checkbox, newHolder.mCheckBox);
        convertView.setTag(R.id.txtValue, newHolder.mEditText);
    } else {
        newHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }


    newHolder.mCheckBox.setTag(position); 
    newHolder.mEditText.setTag(position);
    //newHolder.mEditText.addTextChangedListener(this); Remove this
    setEdit(list.get(position).isEnabled());

    //Added Change here...Check if arraylist contains selectedposition or not?

    if(selectedPosition.contains(String.valueOf(position))){
           list.get(getPosition).setSelected(compoundButton.isChecked());
            list.get(getPosition).setEnabled(compoundButton.isChecked());
            setEdit(compoundButton.isChecked());
    }else{
           setEdit(false);
           list.get(getPosition).setValue("");
    }

   //Same way compare for edittext

   if(editHash.containsKey(Integer.parseInt(position))){
       newHolder.mEditText.setText(editHash.get(position));
    }else{
       newHolder.mEditText.setText("");
    }

    newHolder.mCheckBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {

        int position = (int) compoundButton.getTag();
        //Simply store and check selectedPosition

       if(!b)
           selectedPosition.remove(String.valueOf(position));
       else
           selectedPosition.add(String.valueOf(position));

       //And then update adapter
       notifyDataSetChanged();

        }
    });

   //Let's add Textwatcher for our Edittext
   newHolder.mEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

             int position = (int) newHolder.mEditText.getTag();
             //Storing into Hashmap
             editHash.put(position, s.toString());

        }
    });


    return convertView;
}
```

Comment: Why a list of strings instead of integers?

Comment: @cricket_007 : yeah we could take list of integers also. doesn't matter. I only took string because when you apply add and remove operation it assmes position of arraylist you want to remove instead of value container. So it's bit easy with string

Comment: I think you're right. Adding and remove int primitives will perform auto-boxing

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but that doesn't solve the issue. First of all, list.get(getPosition).setSelected()` and `list.get(getPosition).setEnabled()` are working fine. That's the reason I'm able to enable/disable `EditText` by checking. Your code only confirms if the checkbox at current position is checked or not, which is already working fine.

I particularly need to identify row number/id of the `EditText` user clicked so the `TextWatcher` can save the text to the corresponding `EditText`.

Comment: @NagarajuGajula : yeah I got something, I have updated my answer. Kindly check it. I took hashmap to store value for particular edittext and then compared it

Comment: @NagarajuGajula : Let me know does it work for you or not?

Comment: Using `notifyDatasetChanged` within `TextWatcher` made it inaccessible. `EditText` is enabled, but couldn't type anything. It doesn't even display cursor. So, I guess it reloads as soon as is active.

Comment: Removing `notifyDatasetChanged` within `TextWatcher` solved input issue, but there are other problems. Whenever I check/uncheck `checkbox`, all `EditText` are reset with value of first row. Testing with some changes. I will update if it works.

Comment: @NagarajuGajula : have you removed this newHolder.mEditText.addTextChangedListener(this);  line from your code?

Comment: @NagarajuGajula : I tested all changes I made here with getView() method. It's working fine for me. So check once you are not missing anything to update in your code yet

Comment: @NagarajuGajula : I have added this  int position = (int) newHolder.mEditText.getTag(); in textWatcher to get proper position while storing data